# In Python, io.StringIO codec writer gets string in input but gives "TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'"

Tags: python, io

Simple example

```
import codecs
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
writer = codecs.getwriter('UTF-8')
buffer_writer = writer(buffer)
buffer_writer.write('[]')
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 378, in write
    self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

I dind`t understand the error.
I need buffer to be an io.StringIO object.

Comment: Why do you need the `codecs.getwriter('UTF-8')`? Strings in Python 3 are UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Why not use `io.BytesIO()` instead of StringIO() when handling bytes? See [IO doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for the information, I think writing directly in the buffer would solver my problem.

Comment: @Kakedis but I`m not handling bytes, I`m handling strings, and it says it expected a string.